# Limit in ignited datatable

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatable, limit

```
$this->db->select('employee_name');
$this->db->from('employee');
$this->db->limit(1,0);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

How to write this query in datatable. I wrote query as below.

```
$this->datatable->select('employee_name')
->from('employee');
$this->datatable->limit(1,0);
return $this->datatables->generate();
```

But it shows error in limit.

Comment: Method `limit()` is not defined in datatables library. I am still looking for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used codeigniter method chaining along the general query,try any of these

By Method Chaining

```
$this->datatables->select('employee_name')
                ->from('employee')
                ->limit(1);
return $this->datatables->generate();
```

another way

```
$this->datatables->select('employee_name');
$this->datatables->from('employee');
$this->datatables->limit(1);
return $this->datatables->generate();
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I tried both codes. But found an error,"Call to undefined method Datatables::limit()".

Comment: Found any solutions for this?